# install4j error out with Splash.png is not a valid image file

Tags: png, install4j

I saw a post to this very issue and the author have resolved it my edit the png splash file. However,
in my case I did not made any changes to the png file, and yet, i ran into this error with install4j.
Please help if some one have resolved this.

```
[install4j] java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
[install4j]     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.writeBytes(Native Method)
[install4j]     at java.io.RandomAccessFile.write(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at com.sun.media.imageioimpl.plugins.bmp.BMPImageWriter.write(BMPImageWriter.java:513)
[install4j]     at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at com.A.B.D.W(ejt:2330)
[install4j]     at com.A.B.D.Q(ejt:2859)
[install4j]     at com.A.B.D.L(ejt:1319)
[install4j]     at com.A.B.D.N(ejt:463)
[install4j]     at com.A.B.D.d(ejt:555)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.D.F.B(ejt:833)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.D.B.R(ejt:629)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.D.I(ejt:3315)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.D.C(ejt:776)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.A.A(ejt:1596)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.B.¦(ejt:1736)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.B.+(ejt:3290)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.C.B.I(ejt:659)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.?(ejt:3031)
[install4j]     at com.A.L.?(ejt:2517)
[install4j]     at com.install4j.Install4JApplication.main(ejt:3481)
[install4j]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[install4j]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at com.exe4j.runtime.LauncherEngine.launch(Unknown Source)
[install4j]     at com.exe4j.runtime.WinLauncher.main(Unknown Source)
[install4j] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: com.A.B.E: com.A.B.E: File Splash.png is not a valid image file.
```

Comment: What version of install4j do you use?

Comment: Thanks Ingo, I am using install4j-4.2.2

Comment: I also found that the when my png file properties was readonly (RA) it failed with the error and when I changed it to writable (A), it's no longer has the error and install4j completed successfully.

Comment: Well, false alarm, I just tried with a fresh sync and the files after synced down already changed the RA (readonly) to A (writable) prior to start to build workbench component.  It still failed no matter what I did to the file by switching it between RA and A.

Comment: It is so flaky behavior that at this point I am not sure what is the cause...

Answer (score 0):

Up to release 4.2.7, install4j included a JAR file

```
[install4j installation directory]/lib/jai-imageio.jar
```

This JAR file contains an ancient implementation of javax.imageio and was a leftover from times when that API was not part of the JRE (prior to Java 1.3).

Just delete that JAR file and the problem will most likely go away.

Comment: Many thanks to Ingo. Upon deletion the jai_imageio.jar, I can run my builds and they are consistently working fine after a couple of builds. Again, I greatly appreciate your help.